# In-class initializer of std::array constexpr with MS Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

The following code is not building with Visual Studio 2015 Community edition

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <array>

template<size_t... INDEX> struct test
{
    typedef std::array<size_t, sizeof...(INDEX)> storage_type;
    constexpr static storage_type index = { {INDEX...} };
};

int main()
{
    test<2, 3, 4, 5> test_instance;
    return 0;
}
```

This code works well with GCC 4.9. With Visual Studio I get three errors, all realated to the line with the `constexp`:

- C2133 `'?? ??::?? ::index': unkown size`
- C2864 `'test<INDEX...>::index': a static data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile const integral type`
- C2100 `illegal indirection`

In particular the last one, the `illegal indirection` is totally elusive to me.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: to the best of my knowledge, VS doesn't support different modes. It always operates in its currently supported c++11/14 subset.

Comment: It works with a raw array instead of `std::array`. It fails with a raw array in a `struct`, just like shown. Should be reported as bug to Microsoft connect.

Comment: I agree with @Cheersandhth.-Alf, smells like a bug to me.

Comment: Change the `return` statement to `return test_instance.index[0]` and compile with g++, to see another problem.

Comment: It may be that you can use [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) instead of or as foundation for what you're attempting.

Comment: Hi folks. Thanks for your quick replies. It works with raw arrays. I guess it should be possible for me to modify my current code to use a raw array instead of std::array.